# Gradle build release all flavors at once

Tags: android, gradle

I am creating an android app and i have 3 flavors of it. Is there a way that i can write a script within Gradle which will call assembleRelease on all the flavors that i have for it with a single command as opposed to running each release command independently?

Comment: Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307444/gradle-build-only-a-flavour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out that the command that i want is actually called `assembleRelease`. LOL.

Comment: Ha, I've been looking for this for a while.  Thanks!