# Gradle: How to Build different flavours of different built types?

Tags: android, build, gradle

Could someone tell me if it's possible to build only one of my different flavors through the command-line?

At the moment I haven't seen the way to execute, for example:

```
gradle buildDev
```

when Dev is one of my different flavors. Indeed, I have to execute:

```
gradle build
```

And all flavors are build.

I'd like to skip some flavors. 
is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: first try to run `gradle` without params, then read output ... there will be hint to run `gradle tasks` ...

Answer (score 182, accepted):

While there is no flavor-specific version of the `build` task, there are flavor-specific versions of the `assemble` and `install` tasks. `assemble` will create the APK; `install` will install it on devices/emulators.

For example, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloProductFlavors), I define two product flavors (`chocolate` and `vanilla`) and three total build types (`debug`, `release`, and `mezzanine`).

Running **`gradle tasks`** shows, among others:

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
assembleChocolate - Assembles all builds for flavor Chocolate
assembleChocolateDebug - Assembles the Debug build for flavor Chocolate
assembleChocolateDebugTest - Assembles the Test build for the ChocolateDebug build
assembleChocolateMezzanine - Assembles the Mezzanine build for flavor Chocolate
assembleChocolateRelease - Assembles the Release build for flavor Chocolate
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds
assembleMezzanine - Assembles all Mezzanine builds
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds
assembleTest - Assembles all the Test applications
assembleVanilla - Assembles all builds for flavor Vanilla
assembleVanillaDebug - Assembles the Debug build for flavor Vanilla
assembleVanillaDebugTest - Assembles the Test build for the VanillaDebug build
assembleVanillaMezzanine - Assembles the Mezzanine build for flavor Vanilla
assembleVanillaRelease - Assembles the Release build for flavor Vanilla

Install tasks
-------------
installChocolateDebug - Installs the Debug build for flavor Chocolate
installChocolateDebugTest - Installs the Test build for the ChocolateDebug build
installChocolateMezzanine - Installs the Mezzanine build for flavor Chocolate
installChocolateRelease - Installs the Release build for flavor Chocolate
installVanillaDebug - Installs the Debug build for flavor Vanilla
installVanillaDebugTest - Installs the Test build for the VanillaDebug build
installVanillaMezzanine - Installs the Mezzanine build for flavor Vanilla
installVanillaRelease - Installs the Release build for flavor Vanilla
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallChocolateDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build for flavor Chocolate
uninstallChocolateDebugTest - Uninstalls the Test build for the ChocolateDebug build
uninstallChocolateMezzanine - Uninstalls the Mezzanine build for flavor Chocolate
uninstallChocolateRelease - Uninstalls the Release build for flavor Chocolate
uninstallVanillaDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build for flavor Vanilla
uninstallVanillaDebugTest - Uninstalls the Test build for the VanillaDebug build
uninstallVanillaMezzanine - Uninstalls the Mezzanine build for flavor Vanilla
uninstallVanillaRelease - Uninstalls the Release build for flavor Vanilla
```

Comment: Then, when I want to build the flavour's APK  I have to use the assembleXXX. Cool. Thanks.

Comment: @Lechon: **`gradle assembleChocolateDebug`** will result in `build/apk/HelloProductFlavors-chocolate-debug-unaligned.apk` being placed in your project. Though, I cannot rule out the possibility that this only works if the flavor is tasty. :-)

Comment: What about just putting assembleDebugTest?  This is like assembleDebug.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: There is no `assembleDebugTest` once you introduce product flavors.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah that is interesting, because when I list my tasks (and I have product flavors) it indeed does show me a task called assembleDebugTest

Comment: @Zainodis: This answer is over a year old, and it is possible that they have added a task that assembles the debug build type for all product flavors.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah true that, thanks for the hint! The Android gradle build system does still undergo a lot of changes it seems.

Comment: @Zainodis: It should slow down some now that Gradle for Android 1.0 has shipped.

Comment: If you have modules, don't forget the module prefix `:<module>:assemble<FlavorName>`

Comment: this link is dead - is there a new one?

Comment: @Dwebtron: If you are simply looking for a `build.gradle` with product flavors, see https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v9.0/Manifest/Merger/app/build.gradle

Comment: Is there a way to specify product flavour as command line argument? More specifically something like `./gradlew assembleDebug -Dflavour=chocolate`?

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal: Use `./gradlew assembleChocolateDebug`.

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely work, I know. I kinda need some sort of way to specify the product flavor as an argument. Actually, I'm using `./gradlew assembleAndroidTest -DtestType=debug` command which basically generates android test debug apk for all flavour, and I'd like to restrict it to a single one. But whenI use `./gradlew assembleFLAVOR1AndroidTest -DtestType=debug` it says task not found.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal: "I kinda need some sort of way to specify the product flavor as an argument" -- sorry, I do not know of a way to do that. If you are using some outer program (e.g., shell script) to run the `./gradlew` command, it could use string concatenation or interpolation to add the flavor in the proper spot in the `assemble...Debug` argument.

Comment: Ohh, that does sounds like a good option. Thanks! I was probably thinking of using variant filters maybe or explore some other built-in gradle stuff before using a script. 
Again thanks!

Comment: How to assemble all release builds for flavor chocolate?

Comment: @Sumit: In this example, there is only one release build for chocolate, so it would be `assembleChocolateRelease`

Comment: I have multiple dimensions and multiple flavors in app, managed by using variantFilter in build.gradle and disable buildType=="debug" flavor, Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 33):

I  would simplify the answer given by @CommonsWare because going through the answer i was litte confused.

Consider these are the product flavours

- Dev
- Preprod
- Prod

Run

> gradlew task

This will list out all Product flavours along with there build types

```
assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds.
assembleDEV - Assembles all DEV builds.
assemblePREPROD - Assembles all PREPROD builds.
assemblePROD - Assembles all PROD builds.
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds.
```

From this you can easily choose the flavours and will generate a build based on that

> gradlew assemblePREPROD

Answer (score 25):

If your productFlavor is chocolate you can do

```
./gradlew assembleChocolateRelease
```

or

```
./gradlew assembleChocolateDebug
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to the above answers, if you want to build an Android Bundle (AAB) then you can use this

```
# build flavor 'flavorName' only
./gradlew bundleFlavorName
```