# Can I build all my gradle build flavors at once?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have several build flavors for an application. I want to build all differently flavored apks at once and find them in my /output folder. I don't want to select each flavor and build it individually. How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't `./gradlew build` build all flavors by default?

Comment: Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307444/gradle-build-only-a-flavour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should run `./gradlew build` at the root of your project.