# Assemble several flavors with gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, circleci

I'm trying to configure gradle build for circle ci, and I'm running into problems.

What I want is to assemble only several of the app flavors, and I can't figure out how.

I want to run

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

but not with all the variants, something like this

```
./gradlew assembleVarARelease, assembleVarBRelease
```

I know it is possible because the Android Studio release tool can, I just don't know how

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have two product flavours say phone and tablet then you will be having tasks as

```
./gradlew assemblePhoneRelease assembleTabletRelease
```

for more details: [Gradle Build only a flavour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307444/gradle-build-only-a-flavour)