# Unable to resolve imports from external dependencies in Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5 + Preview 6

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

After upgrading from the last **Android Studio 2.0** preview to **Preview 5** I'm having trouble with the imports from the `android.support.wearable` package.

Both the main app and Wear app builds and run just fine, but the editor in Android Studio complains that it can't resolve the these imports

```
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView;
import android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView;
```

In the Wear module's build.gradle I have the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':common')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
}
```

As I understand from http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html#EnableAmbient this should work when using the **provided** statement. And it has worked well until the Android Studio upgrade. Am I missing something?

### Update:

**This isn't just a problem with the Wear library, it's general for what seems to be any external dependency.** (Topic originally was *Unable to resolve package android.support.wearable in Android Studio 2.0 Preview 5*.)

It seems like the problem can occur at any time, but in practice it happens mostly whenever I do lotsa changes in a class (maybe changes to the imports?). Just now it suddenly was unable to resolve the imports of Play Services and Facebook ads (while still working for other dependencies).

**I accidentally found a workaround of the problem:** If I open and build the project in Android Studio 1.5 which I also have installed, all the imports are fixed. Going back to Android Studio 2.0 I can continue programming without the imports becoming unresolvable for a long while.

For anyone googling the problem, the error message in Android Studio is the usual *Cannot resolve symbol '[package]'*.

Comment: So, it's just AS which complains but it builds and runs just fine?

Comment: Yep, even though I have cleaned the project lotsa times, restarted AS, resynced after Gradle scripts changes, restarted my computer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem even before with AS 1.5, the easiest way for me to fix it was to use the Terminal inside Android Studio and execute:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

This will work if you're not using flavors if not just use the name of the flavor, for e.g:

```
./gradlew assembleFlavorNameDebug
```

that should work too as a workaround without leaving your current instance of AS, and then the compiler recognizes your imports if everything is setup properly.

For more references please look: http://tools.android.com/build/gradleplugin
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21307568/799162